# How to structure API service app architecture

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, architecture

### Background:

I'm building an API service app. The app is just like any other, you send an HTTP request and receive a response. This seems simple up until I start thinking about user registration, payments, authentication, logging and so on.

### Application:

tl;dr [simple app diagram](https://app.diagrams.net/?lightbox=1&highlight=0000ff&edit=_blank&layers=1&nav=1#R7Vhbb5swGP01kbaHTVxCQh%2BbNGsndVulPrTpS%2BWCC14czIxTwn797GADxrnQLG2iaVIU2ccX4HzH37Hdc8fz5SUFafyNhBD3HCtc9tyLnuPYfcfpiZ8VFiUy7HslEFEUyk41cIt%2BQwlaEl2gEGZaR0YIZijVwYAkCQyYhgFKSa53eyZYf2oKImgAtwHAJnqHQhaXqO9ZNX4FURSrJ9uWbJkD1VkCWQxCkjcgd9Jzx5QQVpbmyzHEgjzFSznuy4bW6sUoTFiXAY83P2bpw9XoV3GN0ukdHHyPrz4pmjNWqC%2BGISdAVgllMYlIAvCkRkeULJIQimktXqv7XBOSctDm4E%2FIWCGjCRaMcChmcyxb4RKx%2B0Z5Kqb67MnaxVLOvKoUqpIwWtw3K41RoloPW9XUOJMmJSNAI8i2cCOFKvhoDJTkXkIyh%2Fw5vAOFGDD0ogsGSN1FVb9q6A1B%2FFUcS64Rx5cxKNSasfQpMrKgAZSj6gDzQuM1amgV9tdIoHzaC8AL%2BQk5fDJUocc8jxGDtykIRGvOV74e342cv0DK4HIrm6p10GJFKTWvV6GtllbcWIEDa3MANOpey5Nr8DRJwlTG0j46YZ7vaoQNj81XfxtfzsnxZXvHJswzCDu%2F%2BSosEDCYg%2BLojLl9%2F8SW5MBgzHSzJDwX2wBeCzDIMhRwMjKe%2B5kJNx1qT7fZx9k2hqZM%2FLsVs9PJ3I5O1giktyaOCvtLw%2BsPWyvP7WZ45kSuPlGV89REJTHGRDzyYjlV3VZJKXsLbx3%2BF2gngfZPS6Bta%2Bi4IzMm8s5aE9mnJlDfEOgFYOAJZLAnMvkAc2ZHT5SXIlH6sMgg5S%2FCH2ZhEmVrO4EkFO%2B%2BYPHjDBbZx5MzLufs2MZlO%2B%2BQGOpcMG227UgMdTKYNnPBgROD3zExdD2DvVNisFpCcvZ1Lk8%2F3VRnwB2J4WBnPvMwczD9rdWRvVVHBz%2Fb79Rf1zsA%2F6T055zp%2BnOtPfVnZETvnfVnHg7HMQxmDd8QxZWRBBTyA1BlOC2VcgtgugAzRskMjgkmlCMJScSV1TPCuAUBjKJEqJiLB3J8JAwFBQCfy4Y5CsPVfdc6h9I97AAm1bdbKWHN6cr3TGk5w7fyKPM8OlahSGDO%2FxubgRQUc%2FHtq4rICpzBxh6g2jGg5N%2BNoD1sLSp3aG4z1M2Hlh22JIINIeTV%2Bua4XJX1%2Fbs7%2BQM%3D)

**Endpoints** listening for HTTP requests and doing all the request related work. This is the core of the service, what the service user would use this app for. Directly not accessible to the end user (unless somehow it knows the url). Python flask server, deployed on google cloud RUN.

**API gateway** acting like a proxy and a single access point forwarding the requests to the endpoints. This is the service access point for the end users. This part will also be responsible for authentication, limitations, logging and tracking the use of the API endpoints. Python flask server, deployed on google cloud RUN.

**Website** including documentation, demo and show off of API calls through API gateway, registration, payment (thinking of Stripe) etc. VueJS app on NodeJS server on google cloud compute VM.

**Database** storing credentials of registered users, payment information and auth keys. Not implemented yet.

### Problems:

1. Is this architecture proper? What could be done differently or improved? How could I further simplify all the interactions between separate parts of the app? Am I not missing any essential parts?
2. Haven't yet implemented the database part and I'm not sure what should I
   use? There are plenty of [options on google cloud](https://cloud.google.com/products/databases). Also I could go with something simple and just install a DB with http/JSON interface on google cloud compute VM. How do I chose the DB? Given such an app, what would be the best choice?
3. Please recommend literature/blogs/other sources of info on similar app
   architecture for new developers not familiar with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty open ended, but here are some general comments:

Think about how your UI will work. Are you setting up a static app served directly from cloud storage or do you need something rendered on the server? Personally I prefer separating UI from API when I can but you need to be aware of things like search engine optimization. Even if you need to render some content dynamically your site can still be static. Take a look at static site generators like Gatsby. I haven't had to implement a server rendered UI in years and that makes me happy.

API gateway might be fine, but you don't really need it for anything. It might be simpler to start without it and concentrate on what actually matters. If your APIs are being called by an external client you can't trust the calls anyways and any API key you might be using will be exposed. I'd say don't worry about it for a single app. That being said, if you definitely want to use a GW then use one, just be aware that it is mostly a glorified proxy and not some core part of your architecture.

Make sure your API implementations don't store any local state so you can rely on Cloud Run scaling your services up and down. **Definitely don't ever store state directly inside your containers.** If you need state on the server it needs to be in some external data store.

Use JWTs or an external IDM (that will generate JWTs) for authentication. Keep session data on the client side as much as possible and pass the JWT in every API call to authenticate the caller. If you are implementing login on your own the only APIs you need to expose without tokens are for auth and password recovery, which you can separate into their own service.

Database selection depends on how well you understand your processes, how transactional your services are and your existing skillset. Overall I would use what you are comfortable with, you can probably succeed with a lot of things. Certain NoSQL flavors can seem simple on the surface but if you don't have a clear understanding on the types of queries you need to run they can get tedious to work with. Generally you should stick to relational databases for OLAP style implementations and consider NoSQL for OLTP. Personally I like MongoDB and it is very popular, probably because it sort of sits in the middle of the pack which makes it fit a lot of applications. Using MongoDB also makes you cloud agnostic since it is available on every platform. Using platform specific database flavors can lock you down to a specific vendor.

**Whatever you do, don't start installing things on VMs.** You can be almost 100% sure you are doing it wrong  if this comes up. Remember, the services you consume don't all have to be managed by Google or even run on GCP. You can get MongoDB capacity directly from MongoDB who manage it on your behalf on all of the Big3 cloud vendors.

At least think about the long term, even if you don't necessarily need to have it impact your architecture right now. If you are expecting your app to be up for years try to make it more platform agnostic than less. This might mean sticking away from some really platform specific serverless features that will force you to jump a couple of extra hoops. If you are using Cloud Run you are using containers which already makes your app pretty portable, don't lock it to one platform by using a lot of platform specific features. That being said, don't stay away from them either. You should always go for the low hanging fruit, so don't try to avoid using things like secrets manager etc. If your app has a short lifespan and you need really fast time to market then don't worry about it.

Just my 2c, what you are doing is very generic and can be done in a lot of different ways.